Graphics not appearing at the correct time in CodeHS
I am doing a project for school on CodeHS using Javascript. It is a game in which the user tries to move a character across the screen by pressing numbers to indicate which direction they want it to go. The character only moves if they press the correct directions of the "secret" path in the points array.
The game seems to be working fine, but there is a problem with the graphics. The gameboard and character (called by the drawGrid and draw character functions) are supposed to appear right at the beginning, but they are not appearing until after the game is finished. Is there a way to fix this?
Here are the important parts of the code. The screen is 400 x 480. We are required for the project to have one function with a parameter, loop, and conditional in it, and I am using the move function  for this purpose.
var CHARACTER_X = 25;
var CHARACTER_Y = 395;

function start(){
    drawGrid();
    var points = [1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4];
    move(points);
}

function drawGrid(){
// Code that uses loops to draw 4 vertical and 4 horizontal grid lines
}

function drawCharacter(x, y){
// Code that draws a small character
}

function move(arr){
    var character = drawCharacter(CHARACTER_X, CHARACTER_Y);
    add(character); 
    var nextDirection = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i<16; i++){
        var guess = readInt("Pick 1 for up, 2 for down, 3 for left, or 4 for right. ");
        if(guess == arr[nextDirection]){
            remove(character);
            if(guess == 1){
                CHARACTER_Y -= 96;
                character = drawCharacter(CHARACTER_X, CHARACTER_Y);
                add(character);
            }
            if(guess == 4){
                CHARACTER_X += 80;
                character = drawCharacter(CHARACTER_X, CHARACTER_Y);
                add(character);
            }
            nextDirection ++;
        }
        if(CHARACTER_X == 345 && CHARACTER_Y == 11){
            break;
        }
    }
}

I have tried to move around where the drawGrid and draw character functions are called, but the graphics are still not appearing until the end. I have also tried to use setTimeout to call the move functions, but it has not worked.

Your loop for(var i = 1; i<16; i++){ } might not be giving the browser a chance to render the graphics. Please create a [mre]. Also, I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?

@001 How would the loop be preventing the browser from adding the graphics?

Without seeing all the code, it's hard to say. But one option might be to use setTimeout() to call the move() function instead of a loop. Simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/2fkohws7/

Actually you should probably draw everything at beginning and move it afterwards only. Also hiding and showing are possible after drawing.
